# Predict predictable network interface names before rebooting?

Tags: linux, network-interface

I actually like predictable interface names I just want to know them before rebooting after a Debian dist-upgrade so that I can change the `/etc/network/interfaces` accordingly. Any idea how to predict them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** when you upgrade a Debian system that originally used old-style names, it will keep using old-style names by default: the upgrade process will place a symlink to /dev/null as `/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link` which will override the new naming policy file `/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link`. If you choose to use the new style, just `rm /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link` before rebooting after the upgrade.

If the new version of `udev` ruleset is already in place (as you indicated: after `apt dist-upgrade` but before rebooting), then

```
udevadm info -q all -p /sys/class/net/<current name of interface> |grep ID_NET_NAME
```

should display all the naming options, in the order of descending priority:

- ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD `enoN` will appear if there is DMI information identifying the network interface as an on-board integrated NIC. By default, this name takes priority over all other options.
- if the NIC is in a PCIe hot-plug slot, you may see a ID_NET_NAME_SLOT `ensN` number identifying the corresponding slot number
- ID_NET_NAME_PATH `enpNsM` corresponds to PCI device id N:M.0. Unfortunately the device name numbers are in decimal, while PCI device IDs use hexadecimal, so some conversion may be in order.
- if a NIC has multiple ports that appear as separate PCI functions (PCI id N:M.L), then ID_NET_NAME_PATH will be `enpNsMfL` instead.
- there is also the ID_NET_NAME_MAC `enx<MAC address in hex>` format. This is not used by default, but might be convenient on USB-connected NICs.

---

If you don't have even run the upgrade yet, then the procedure would be:

- first, run `dmidecode -t10`. If it reports any Ethernet interfaces, they will be listed as onboard ones (`enoN`).
- if you have NICs in *hot-plug capable* PCIe slots, your hardware manual will hopefully identify the slot numbering.
- then, use `ethtool -i ethN | grep bus-info` to see the PCI bus identifier of a NIC. Convert the bus ID numbers from hex to decimal and you'll know the `enp...` form of the new names. For example:

  bus-info: 0000:00:19.0

will map to enp0s25, and a dual-port NIC with

```
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
```

and

```
bus-info: 0000:01:00.1
```

will map to `enp1s0f0` and `enp1s0f1`.

If you want to tweak the default naming, you can do it with `.link` files in `/etc/systemd/network/` directory: see `man systemd.link` for details. For example, if you want to use the `enx<MAC>` style naming for USB network interfaces, you can add file `/etc/systemd/network/81-usbnet.link` with the following contents:

```
[Match]
Path=*usb*

[Link]
NamePolicy=database mac
```